# how to fix error failed to mark memory page as executable

Tags: java, centos8, springframework

> Nov 28 12:29:01 VM-ECTS-LS-TST systemd[1]: ects.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.\

> Nov 28 12:29:11 VM-ECTS-LS-TST systemd[1]: ects.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 6.\

> Nov 28 12:29:11 VM-ECTS-LS-TST systemd[1]: Stopped ECTS TEST 3.\

> Nov 28 12:29:11 VM-ECTS-LS-TST systemd[1]: Started ECTS TEST 3.\

> Nov 28 12:29:11 VM-ECTS-LS-TST java[1098]: Error occurred during initialization of VM\

> Nov 28 12:29:11 VM-ECTS-LS-TST java[1098]: Failed to mark memory page as executable - check if grsecurity/PaX is enabled

Comment: check if grsecurity/PaX is enabled